# eas build error: Provisioning profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info entitlement

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, eas

Getting error with `eas build --platform ios`

error: Provisioning profile doesn't match the entitlements file's value for the com.apple.developer.networking.wifi-info entitlement.

When I am running `expo build:ios` then getting no error.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

You can add this capability to the app:

1. Go to https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/identifiers/list
2. Click the app identifier
3. Enable "Access WiFi Information"

Or, you can remove this capability from the Entitlements file:

1. In xCode, in the target settings, choose the "Signing & Capabilities" tab
2. Click the Trash icon next to "Access WiFi Information"